# Debugging Jupyter notebook: stepping through a cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipdb

In a blank Jupyter notebook I enter the following code in a cell:

```
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace
set_trace()
print("hello")
```

After running the cell, I get into debug mode (first screenshot). I want to step to the next line, so I use the command n(ext), as I do in pdb. But then I don't step to the print command, as I expected, but to some internal IPython code (second screenshot). How can I go to the next line in the cell code?

[image]

**EDIT**: As suggested by one answer, I substitute `set_trace()` with `breakpoint()`, but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.7 includes built-in [breakpoint()](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-553-built-in-breakpoint) function. All you need to do enter:

```
breakpoint()
```

wherever you would like runtime to stop. You can use the same commands from pdb to move next, continue, run, ...

Comment: This is certainly easier than importing set_trace() and calling it, but it doesn't solve my problem, I still end up in interactiveshell.py when I type next.